# Turned flipper off and still getting Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm getting this error in my React-Native iOS app:

```
Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')
```

Which usually means that flipper is enabled, and is causing problems. However, in my case, flipper is off:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'Newr Remote' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'Newr RemoteTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  #post_install do |installer|
  #  react_native_post_install(installer)
  #  __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  #end
end
```

I've already tried a pod install. What could I be missing?

Comment: You can comment out the offending line in Time.h (line 52, I believe), which is irritating, but does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it temporarily by commenting out the offending line in Time.h as @jnpdx recommended I do.
I think this may have been fixed in a recent update, as I don't see this error anymore.